# Find the next day in an array of dates

Tags: arrays, matlab, date

I have an array of `datenum`s in MATLAB such that each row is a new date.

I would like to create an array that is the next day for each row of my array.
How do I do this?

I am familiar with `datetime('tomorrow')` but how do I do this with an array of past dates?

Comment: Then why don't you create that array? What is your question here?

Comment: How do I do this?

I am familiar with datetime('tomorrow') but how do I do this with an array of past dates

Comment: Not exact dup but the answer is what you are after.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need [`datenum`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datenum.html)

> `DateNumber = datenum(t)` converts the datetime values in datetime array
>   t to serial date numbers. A serial date number represents the whole
>   and fractional number of days from a fixed, preset date (January 0,
>   0000) in the proleptic ISO calendar.

So simply add 1 to your full vector, then convert back to `datetime` if necessary, and you have your following date for each date presented.